# doctrine path setting

Tags: mysql, doctrine, database-connection

My mysql connection setting:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("fanyer.fatcowmysql.com", "test_username", "test_password") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
  mysql_select_db("fanyer_database") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Connected to Database";
?>
```

This is working perfectly.. Now i am using this in doctrine bootstrap file.

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://test_username:test_password@fanyer.fatcowmysql.com/fanyer_database', 'doctrine');
```

Giving an error

> Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with
>   message 'Couldn't locate driver named
>   mysql'

EDIT:
changing it to sql
**Unknown driver sql**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable pdo_mysql in your php.ini as Gonzaloand mentioned and  check whether your host is supporting it or not cause i faced the same problem while hosting my application on fatcow as they people dont hav support for pdo

Answer (score 1):

I thought maybe it should be sql://test_username...., but the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/connections) says `mysql:` is right.

Comment: The question is tagged 'mysql'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable **pdo_mysql** in your php.ini. Instructions [here](http://www.hostatree.com/support/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=266).